# SQL combining queries

Tags: sql, count, distinct, where-clause

Currently, I have two separate queries on the same table checking to see how many distinct items there are. In the first query, I'm interested in the number of distinct items within a larger list, while in the second query I'm only interested in a subset of that list. Ultimately I would join the two outputs.

```
 SELECT count(distinct a.item) as items
 FROM table a
 WHERE a.item in ('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10')


 SELECT count(distinct a.item) as specific_items
 FROM table a
 WHERE a.item in ('01','02')
```

Is it possible to condense this into a single query? In the future I'd like to look at other subsets of lists and rather than add more queries and join more tables, I figure there must be a way to optimize this for readability and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    count(distinct a.item) as items,
    count(distinct case when a.item in ('01', '02') then a.item end) as specific_items
from table a
where a.item in ('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10')
```

Note: is `item_id` really of a string datatype? If it is a number, then I would recommend comparing it against numbers instead. And if it's an integer, then you can simplify the `where` clause as follows:

```
select 
    count(distinct a.item) as items,
    count(distinct case when a.item in (1, 2) then a.item end) as specific_items
from table a
where a.item between 1 and 10
```

Depending on your database, which you did not disclose, there may be neater solutions available. For example, Postgres and SQLite support the standard `filter` clause, which lets you rewrite the second count as:

```
count(distinct a.item) filter(where a.item in (1, 2)) as specific_items
```